# Appcelerator Titanium iOS - ti.main.js file not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

`iOS` app stuck in splash screen then shows error **ti.main.js** file not found error. I installed latest titanium version. The error screen shot follows. Pl. advice.

**Reproduce steps.**

- Create titanium mobile project (alloy or classic)
- Build your project via Studio or CLI, then close the simulator
- Open project/build/iphone/yourproject.xcodeproj in Xcode.
- Build & run the project within Xcode.

> **Operating System**
>
> Name                        = Mac OS X,   Version
>   = 10.14.3,   Architecture                = 64bit,   # CPUs                      = 4,   Memory                      = 10.0GB
>
> **Node.js**
>
> Node.js Version             = 10.15.3,   npm Version
>   = 6.4.1
>
> **Titanium CLI**
>
> CLI Version                 = 5.1.1,   node-appc Version           =
>   0.2.44

[image]

Comment: are you using Liveview? Try turning it off and check for output errors

Comment: @miga I think I don't use live view, Note that I'm building from xcode. How can I ensure that I don't use live view?

Comment: when compiling don't add --liveview, or when using studio don't have the liveview button enabled

Comment: @RenePot I din't do that, I added steps to reproduce can u check please?

Comment: I believe recompiling with xcode is not really supported, why do you need it?

Comment: @RenePot So, there is no way to run app using xcode, as I'm running the studio in trial version It's impossible to release the app update.

Comment: @RenePot But previously I was able to build from xcode, Its before one year, Is this restriction came in new SDK version?

Comment: @Stella just claim the free indie seat in the platform login. Titanium is 100% free to use. Or use the titanium CLI that doesn't require an account. You can also get the vscode or atom plugin

Comment: @RenePot Thank u very much for your kind suggestions, I find it very useful, let me check it.